# %sql giving error in apache zeppelin hdinsight spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I got spark cluster up in HdInsight and able to open up Zepplin as well but %sql seems to work at random, most of the times it simply throws error without any error message and just shows error in the paragraph.

Comment: I am not familiar with HdInsight thus It would be nice if you describe env more. For example version of zeppelin, spark, backend (jdbc engine) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

HDInsight just released new version of Zeppelin 0.7 as part of HDInsight 3.6 version. It has range of stability improvements. Please try it out, it works well for me so far.

Maxim